# Ball roll animation using jquery or CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to change this code so that the balls rolled out. 
but:

1. Indicate the number of balls (for example 10).
2. Once rolled out one ball and stopped, then rolls out the next ball
   (and gets close to another).
3. And that they rolling from the right side to the left side.

**html**

```
<div id="balls">
    <img src="http://i058.radikal.ru/1407/0d/33cc119c6686.png" id="ball" />
</div>
```

**css**

```
body {
    background: #383838;
}
#balls {
    position: absolute;
}
#balls img {
    position: absolute;
}
#ball {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    left: 170px;
    top: 45px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var diameter = $('#ball').height(),
    perimeter = Math.PI * diameter;

var goLeft;
var times = 0;
var to = [600, 600];

function moveBalls() {
    goLeft = !goLeft;
    times++;
    if (times > to.length) {
        return false;
    }
    $('#balls').animate({
        right: to[times]
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        step: rotateBall,
        complete: moveBalls
    });
}
moveBalls();

function rotateBall(distance) {
    var degree = distance * 360 / perimeter;
    $('#ball').css('transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
}
```

***Example*** [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nazaret2005/9Z5zd/)

Comment: It's probably possible. Please show what you tried to achieve your goals and we'll help you further from where you have problems with it

Comment: (OT) The way you're rolling that ball from a designer perspective is totally funny... you're actually not rolling the ball (see the light source?) but the viewer camera :D

Comment: @Spokey I want balls rolled out one after the other like in the game lotto.

Comment: Also to make it roll in the right direction use `-` here: `var degree = -distance * 360 / perimeter;` http://jsfiddle.net/9Z5zd/1/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Thanks. And other correct desing i will do in the end, first need way to create the script game )))

Comment: @Nazaret2005 no, don't do it in the end. Do it now ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/nupaz/3/edit)**

[image]

To get a better result you should have 3 elements for `ball`:

- one that moves right with a static light source and shadow
- rotate the inner DIV element
- a SPAN with number -> inside the rotating DIV.

Use CSS3 transitions like I did.

```
<div id="balls">
    <div class="ball blue">        <!-- THIS ONE JUST MOVES RIGHT -->
        <div><span>7</span></div>  <!-- THIS ONE ROTATES -->
    </div>
    <!-- MORE BALLS HERE -->
</div>
```

Following the above logic the CSS ends up being quite trivial:

```
.ball{
    position:absolute;
    left:-100px;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    background:#004E99;
    border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow: 20px 30px 30px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.ball>div{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.ball>div>span{
    position:absolute;
    left:23px;
    top:14px;
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
    border-radius:50%;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:45px;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#fff;
}
/* YOUR COLORS */
.ball.blue{   background: radial-gradient(circle at 20px 20px, #09f, #001);}
```

JS/jQ:

```
var $ball = $('#balls > div'),
    diameter = $ball.height(),
    perimeter = Math.PI * diameter,
    n = $ball.length,
    i = 0,
    itv;

itv = setInterval(function(){
    if(i>n)clearInterval(itv);
    rotateBall( 500-(diameter*i) );
    i++;
},2000);

function rotateBall(distance) {
  var degree = distance * 360 / perimeter;
  $ball.eq(i).css({
    transition: "2s",
    transform: 'translateX('+ distance +'px)'
  }).find('div').css({
    transition: "2s",
    transform: 'rotate('+ degree +'deg)'    
  });
}
```

Comment: Something i did not get, insert balls in the place where i would like. Width in the page) How to fix it )) (And i have 17 balls in the game)

Comment: I dont understand your question... Is there something im missing from your main post?

Comment: If you wanna play more with balls, like this http://www.pais.co.il/Keno/PublishingImages/simulators/keno.swf here is Action script http://jsfiddle.net/Nazaret2005/J68uM/ :-)

Comment: @Nazaret2005 ? both links are useless... What should I do. The first is dead the second shows .... nothing.

Comment: here is another link http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1406892172 to show the flash (click to the button there). And in jsfiddle.net/Nazaret2005/J68uM just action script from this SWF Animation, watch )))